# Approximating strength and hardness of alloy

Tags: metallurgy

I do not have any formal education in metallurgy, but I am trying to make a game mechanic based on it.

I need to be able to alloy together different metals and alloyable materials such as carbon in different percentages, and get an approximation of the strength and hardness of the resulting alloy. If anyone has any ideas how what I would need to do to calculate such a thing I would be very appreciative.

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Looks too broad - big part of metallurgy - even about steel there are lots of books.

Comment: Hmm, @Mith I *think* the answer could boil down to introducing a general formula $\ldots$ and it doesn't need to be something specific. Are you sure there's no way for a short answer on this?

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M Looks like Todd managed to do this generally enough ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the free resource provided [at MatWeb](http://www.matweb.com/).

Under the Physical Properties tab, you can choose up to 3 of them from a rather extensive list, including hardness. For example, I chose "Carbon" and "Hardness, Rockwell R," and 25 results were returned.

Under the Alloy Composition tab, you can choose up to 3 elements and percentages for your alloy, and see if you get a hit. I chose "Nonferrous Metal" and carbon (minimum 5%, maximum 75%) and silicon (minimum 5%, maximum 75%), and got one hit.

I believe for your purposes, you can assemble a list of materials by hardness and strength (I'm not a metallurgist either, so you might have to do some research on which of the hardness and strength metrics you'll need to choose) and/or by selecting by composition (again, you might need to research which 2- and 3-element combinations make sense and which ones don't).